# Laravel 5 belongsToMany how to get the data in the method all();

Tags: laravel-5, relationship

i used to belongsToMany relationship
i tried
my Resta model

```
public function kitchens()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Kitchen')->withTimestamps();
}
```

my Kitchen model

```
public function resto()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Resto');
}
```

function for return Resto data

```
public function getAllRest($city)
{
    $restos = Resto::latest('created_at')
        ->where('city','=', $city)
        ->get();

    return $restos;
}
```

Now when I have an interface relations, as they output?
In one I know that it is possible to do so

```
 $resta = Resto::find($id);
 $resta->kitchens->toArray();
```

How can I output in the derivation of all the data?

Comment: you want to get all resto and their kitchens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
add this

```
$restos = Resto::latest('created_at')
    ->where('city','=', $city)
    ->get();
foreach($restos as $resto){
   $resto->kitchens->toArray();
}

return $restos;
```